# Are water passing valves supposed to be hard to open and close?

Tags: water, valve, technique

Is a passing valve like this supposed to be hard to open and close?

[image: water passing valve]

The valve is new but it's hard to get open and then get closed. It takes me some force to get it going, but after I do, it slides smoothly. After I apply some force it gives immediately, but then that force has to go somewhere so I end up turning it all the way to closed (or vice versa). I'm worried I might damage the valve or maybe the water pipes.

Is it supposed to be like that? Is there some techniques to open and close this thing so the force I apply is uniform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a ball valve that opens/closes with a 1/4  (90) degree turn and YES they are hard to turn. If you want an easier valve to turn, buy one with a longer handle. Valves that screw in use a mechanical advantage, an action similar to a nut and bolt and are  easier to turn but take longer to open/close. And, remember there is a stop that only allows the valve to turn 90 degrees either way. To make them easier you will have to find one that is easier to turn and replace the existing valve with the easier one.

Comment: Any tips for how to make this one easier to open/close or limit the damage I could do if I apply too much force opening/closing it?

Comment: You'll unlikely ever damage it you are using one hand and supporting it with the other. As mentioned, just use a longer handle and it'll be easier and require less force.